# Javascript regexp for amount and currency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, numbers, decimal

Can anyone please provide me with regexp for these things ( i am using input for text ):

1. Only numbers allowed
2. Minimal number 20
3. Maximum number 300
4. Max two decimals spaces
5. Allow comma or fullstop. eg. 15,45 or 15.45

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:[2-9]\d|[1-2]\d{2})(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$|^300(?:[.,]0{1,2})?$
```

Flowchart explanation:

[image]

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qA4eC2/3)

Comment: This is amazing! It is working awesome! Thank youuu @timolawl